# retrive data using multiple table in core data in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Actually I have three tables as empName(empId,empName),empSalary(empId,salary),empBonus(salary,bonus).

And I have a name and need to find the bonus.

So My logic is that first find using name I will find the empId then using empId find the salary and finally using salary find the bonus from empBonus table.

How can I achieve following things in core data in iPhone.

Comment: You can easily use the reverse Relationships to do the following: empName.empSalary.empBonus in your object hierachry

Comment: actually we don't use tables in Core Data. Core Data is not a database!

Answer (score 0):

Use relationships between data, so that whenever you find the name, it also finds the salary and bonus from the other tables. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB)

I would not do raw sqlite queries if you have this level of knowledge of Core Data and Sql.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should stop thinking in tables. Core Data is not a wrapper for SQlite. 
If you want tables don't use Core Data and use SQLite.
Core Data is an object graph and persistence framework. You have entities instead of tables.

Because you are talking about tables I have no idea what you actually want but your Data Model could look like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

(the Employee->Salary relationship in the last screenshot should be to-many, I forgot to put that into the model.)

and because you have an object graph you can get all the objects in that graph.
For the last example model your code could look like this:

```
Employee *myEmployee = /* do a fetch to get an Employee */
NSSet *salaries = myEmployee.salaries;
Salary *salary = /* choose one from the salaries set */
Bonys = salary.bonus;
```

Comment: Thanks for info.According to that I am able to made the relationship.But when trying to use NSSet *salaries = myEmployee.salaries;It is giving o objects found in salaries.Can you please help me.